# How to automate PDF printing of individual forms in MS Access?

Tags: database, forms, ms-access, vba, record

I am trying to print a separate pdf file (billing invoice) from a form for each record in my database.

- Form to print: `BillingInvoice-`
- Source for form: `FamilySubDIscSubDIscGrand`
- Primary field: `Fnum`

I've tried taking code from here:
[How to output multiple PDF files based on record in MS Access?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51333290/how-to-output-multiple-pdf-files-based-on-record-in-ms-access)

This is the code that code as I have tried to modify it:

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Private Sub PrintBtn01_Click()

Dim rsGroup As DAO.Recordset
  Dim ColumnName As String, myPath As String

  myPath = "C:\test\"

  Set rsGroup = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT FNum FROM FamilySubDIscSubDIscGrand", _
                                    dbOpenDynaset)
Do Until rsGroup.EOF
  ColumnName = rsGroup!FNum

  ' OPEN FORM, FILTERING RECORDSOURCE BY COLUMN VALUE
  DoCmd.OpenForm "BillingInvoice-", acViewPreview, , "Column='" & ColumnName & "'"
  ' OUTPUT FORM TO FILE

  DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputForm, "BillingInvoice-", acFormatPDF, _
                                myPath & ColumnName & ".pdf", False

    rsGroup.MoveNext
  Loop

End Sub
```

I’m doing something wrong.

It is successfully saving the pdf’s with the `FNum`s in sequence, but printing the individual records for each `FNum`, it is printing all the records. So I end up with:

```
FNum001.pdf (all records for db)
FNum002.pdf (all records for db)
Fnum003.pdf (all records or db)
...
```

But what I need is:

```
FNum001.pdf (individual record for FNum001)
FNum002.pdf (individual record for FNum002)
FNum003.pdf (individual record for FNum003)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If `FNum` is numerical, you should not surround the criteria value with single quotes, i.e. this:

```
"Column='" & ColumnName & "'"
```

Should become:

```
"Column=" & ColumnName
```

Also, unless you have a field on your form called `Column`, this should be changed to:

```
"FNum = " & ColumnName
```

Comment: Lee Mac, thanks for the help.  I've incorporated your advice and switched to a report rather than a form.  It's coming along, and is certainly better than before.  It's still not fully automated and i'm getting some weird seemingly-unrelated errors (prompts to enter variables that should have been passed to the report, maybe corruption, but probably just something i missed." I'll keep tinkering with it and let you know how it goes.